# The verb "sequence"

Tags: word-usage

I have found out that the verb "sequence" can mean to combine things in a particular order, or discover the order in which they are combined.

Can I use "sequence" the following way?

"The librarian has sequenced the books in some order. As a curious person, I want to sequence those books."

Comment: I'd use ***arranged*** or ***sorted*** (or perhaps ***ordered***) in your context. The verb ***to sequence*** is experiencing a massive increase because we're so busy ***sequencing dna*** these days (***discovering*** the order in which the bases are combined, which is a somewhat different sense of the verb), but that doesn't mean you should apply it everywhere else.

Comment: ...but it's interesting to contemplate a librarian "sequencing" the books in his library in the dna-related "discovery" sense. If he ignored "imposed" sequences, perhaps some meaningful natural sequence might arise whereby the more popular books tended to accumulate near the front door, and our intrepid librarian could win the Nobel prize for librarianship by being the first to research and publish this fact! :)